# How is this small tab feature enabled in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is this an add-on or do we have to edit the style sheet by ourselves?

[image: some tabs are grouped (top left)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature in Firefox called [Pinned Tabs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open). To make a pinned tab, just:

> Right-click on the tab you want to pin and select **Pin Tab** from the menu.